# Unable to center an embedded flickr slideshow with div and CSS

Tags: html, css

The code looks something like this

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="flickr">
        <object width="600" height="450"> ...flickr slideshow code ....</object>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the CSS like this

```
div.body {
    height: 600px;
    width: 1024px;
}

.flickr {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

The embedded object just sticks to the left top of the parent element. None of the centering CSS works on it.

I can specify align="center" in the div in the HTML and get it centered but then the margin-top in CSS won't work on it.

Comment: I assume `text-align: center;` doesn't work? Any chance you could setup a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
.flickr 
{ 
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Please try this code instead of bellow code

```
.flickr 
{ 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```